# Can I read CSV with columns that has specific value(s) using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read a CSV using Pandas but only certain columns and only rows with spicific values. for example I have a csv of "people and their heights", I want to read the "name" column and "height" column of people that are > "160cm" height only. I want to do this in the first step of read_csv() not after loading it.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['name','height']
df = pd.read_csv("people_and_heights.csv", usecols=cols)
```

so I want to add a condition to read rows with certain values only or rows that doesn't have nulls for example.

Comment: why not apply those filters and export it into new csv?

Comment: Are you doing this for the purpose of reducing memory usage, or some other reason?

Comment: If this is a memory issue as @NickODell is suggesting, your best bet is probably to load the .csv in chunks. I don't think you can avoid loading the rows you don't want as they will need to be loaded to check if they meet your criteria.

Comment: exactly @NickODell . I'm thinking to overcome memory issues as I'm dealing with more than 50GB zipped CSV's and many of the rows are useless since it's null or with values that are byonde the scope of my analysis.

Comment: @Pepsi-Joe that would be my last resort really, especially with many CSV's to deal with.

Comment: How large are the individual csv files? It might be worth writing a script to do the filtering and put the data you actually want into a single csv with only the values you need. It will be slow and inefficient, but you only have to do it once (e.g. over a weekend). It sounds like you don't know how much data is useful for further analysis and my next move would be to find out if its 2GB or 20Gb.

Comment: @rfengineer looking at the docs for `pd.read_csv` there is a `skiprows` keyword that allows for a callable function. You may be able to write a function that checks if the data is in range or not. No idea how efficient this will be as it will still have to load every row and run some python it. EDIT: Forget I said that - the function only looks at row indices.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open("people_and_heights.csv") as file:
    colNames = "\"col1\",\"name\",\"col3\",\"height\""
    filteredCsv = "\n".join([colNames,"".join([line for index,line in enumerate(file) if index != 0 and int(line.split(',')[3]) >= 165])])

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(filteredCsv),usecols=["name","height"])
```

Comment: ah right :) I only thought about "I want to do this in the first step of read_csv() not after loading it."  part. I didn't notice the comments sorry :)